# Could someone explain this python code?

Tags: python

```
def censor(text, word):
    return text.replace(word, ("*"*len(word)))
```

This code takes a string 'text' and replaces 'word' in the string with a number of asterisks based on the length of 'word'.

I'm fairly new to Python but I can't figure out how .replace works. From the Python documentation of string, string.replace would seem to take 3 (or 4) arguments. But the code seems to only take two? I'm sure I'm mistaken, but if someone could explain it, that would be great.

Comment: The additional argument is optional as it is a default argument ... From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) *If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.*

Comment: The first argument is `self`, i.e. the string itself, and the fourth is optional.

Comment: You are confounding the (admittedly very confusing) string *class* method `replace` (deprecated) with the string *instance* method `replace`, which is what the code you quoted is using.  See BrenBarn's answer, below.

Comment: @LarryLustig: The other one isn't a class method, it's a function inside the string module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

> `str.replace(old, new[, count])`
>
> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

As you can see, it takes two arguments (and an optional third argument).

You may have been looking at the documentation in the [`string` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace).  However, as it says at the top of that page, the module contains "some deprecated legacy functions that are also available as methods on strings".  In old versions of Python you had to use `string.replace(original_string, replace_this, with_this)`.  Now you can just do `original_string.replace(replace_this, with_this)` and you don't need to import the `string` module at all for most things.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the lengh of word, replacement is created using 'repetation' operator '*'

for example:

```
>>> text = "I like learning python"
>>> word = "like"
>>> len(word)
4
>>> "*"*4
'****'
>>> text.replace(word,"*"*len(word))
'I **** learning python'
```

help(str) has the syntax for replace

|  replace(...)
 |      S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> string
 |
 |      Return a copy of string S with all occurrences of substring
 |      old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
 |      given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, the first argument passed to replace is the string itself. In that code you don't need to pass it explicitly. `word` and `("*"*len(word))` are the 2nd and 3rd arguments. The 4th argument is optional and is an integer specifying the maximum number of occurrences to do a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

```
def censor(text,word):
     mask=("*"*len(word))
     maskedText=text.replace(word,mask)
     return maskedText

text='Hello is somebody home ? Hello'
word='Hello'
censor("hello is somebody home ? hello","hello")
'***** is somebody home ? *****'
```

I have broken down the code for you . 
First we created the mask  which is `*****` since hello has 5 words. Here 
`"*"*len(word)` gives you a string with the character * repeated . 
You may use `"x"*len(word)` and it will give u `xxxxx` for hello.

You use can use  replace all occurances of hello in the text with your newly created mask using the `replace` function in python.

General usage 
1.Masking function

```
 'pattern'*<no of times the pattern should be repeated>
```

Example:

```
"abab"*3
'abababababab'
```

2.Replace function

```
<string>.replace(<word to be replaced>,<word/pattern to be used instead><number of times the occurances of the pattern should be repeated>
```

Example:

```
>>> text='hello hello hello'
>>> text.replace('hello','Hi',2)
'Hi Hi hello'
```

This function gives you a copy of the string .
  If you want to modify your string and replace it with the formatted string use can easily do it by

```
text=text.replace('hello','Hi',2)
```

You can read more about replace function [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm).

General Advice:
When in doubt go to commandline and use 
help()